# Write into another file's resources

Tags: c++

how do I write into another's file resources. 
For example, if i have builder in which you can write email,username. And then builder transfers that information into another's file resources. How can i do that?

I did similar thing using End Of File. Its when you basically write information into file's end. But people said that this method is unreliable and bad, and I should use resources, so how do i do that?   (C++)

How my EOF method works:

stub:

```
int main(){
int filesize = 104448; // File size . (not file size on disk
Settings data;
long int size = MAX_PATH;
char *filename = new char[size];
GetModuleFileNameA(NULL,filename,size);

ifstream fin(filename,ios::binary);  // Gets information that was additionally written into this file 
fin.seekg(filesize);
fin.read((char*)&data,sizeof(Settings)); 

fin.seekg(filesize+sizeof(Settings),ios::end);
size_t len = fin.tellg();
fin.seekg(filesize+sizeof(Settings));
char *bytes = new char[len];    
fin.read(bytes,len);
fin.close();  }
```

builder:

```
Settings data;
data.bytesLength = file.getBytesLength();
data.owner = m_username;

char * bytes = file.getBytes();

ifstream stub("Stub.exe", ios::binary);
ofstream built("Built.exe",ios::binary); 
built << stub.rdbuf();
stub.close();

built.write((char*)&data,sizeof(Settings));
built.write(crc4.Encrypt(file.getBytes(),file.getPassword().c_str()),file.getBytesLength());
built.close();
```